# IE complaining JS syntax error but works on other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Javascript function below works fine using Chrome or Firefox. However seem to get a syntax error in Internet Explorer. Its complaining at ` (syntax error) can someone help me as to why? How can I fix this to work on all browsers.

```
    // Grab the binary mapping of the letter and
// return some HTML
function binaryise(letter) {
    var arr = mapping[letter].split('');
    return arr.map(char => `<div class="${char === '0' ? 'zero' : 'one'}">${char}</div>`).join('');
}

// For each letter in the word create a 
// binary version and return it in a list-item container
function processWord(arr) {
    var items = arr.map((letter, i) => {
        var binaryised = binaryise(letter);
        return `
      <li class="binaryli" data-id=${i}>
        <div class="containerbinary">${binaryised}</div>
      </li>
    `;
    }).join('');
    return `<ul class="binaryul">${items}</ul>`;
}
```

Comment: I only have one thing to say : this is IE, you'd better get used to it ;)

Comment: Consider using Webpack and Babel - it allows you to write in ES6 and have your code transpiled to ES5

Comment: You can try to use this site to convert your code which supports IE. https://babeljs.io/ Here is a converted version of your code. https://textuploader.com/1arjo If you don't want to convert the code using Babel than you need to write the code specifically for IE by yourself.

Comment: Thanks looks like it was the CSS file that was causing an issue in IE not the converted code for JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Internet Explorer does not support Template Literals, which is where backticks (`) are used. You may want to use single quotes (') instead of backticks.

Comment: Thanks - im still getting syntax error on:

function binaryise(letter) {
    var arr = mapping[letter].split('');
    return arr.map(char => '<div class="${char === '0' ? 'zero' : 'one'}">${char}</div>').join('');
}

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported by IE, so you will have to use a regular function.